# Запуск exe файла с помощью планировщика заданий

Tags: python, pyinstaller

На Python был написан скрипт, подключающийся к БД, формирующий excel файл с данными оттуда и отправляющий все это дело на почту по SMTP, необходимо проделывать эти действия один раз в день в определенное время.
Я использовал pyinstaller, чтобы сделать из него exe файл. Файл при запуске из проводника выполняет свою задачу отлично. Но если создавать задачу в планировщике заданий, то файл не выполняется и задача выдает ошибку 0x1. Я подозреваю, что нужно указать дополнительные аргументы в планировщике, но не знаю какие.

[image]

Comment: Судя по гуглу что то связанное с интернетом, скорее всего ваш EXE-ник нужно добавить в брандмауэр. В поиске проблемы может помочь журнал планировщика в папке Windows с именем Schedlgu.txt.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что excel-файл формировался в той же директории, что лежал exe, достаточно было поменять его путь на любой другой.